# How to .find a ''a'' in a p in other p, in a div, in a div. with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

[This is what the HTML code im looking at looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A1wD.jpg)

I've been trying to get the year (année) and the ''kilométrage''

so far ive been trying

```
année = page2.find(
```

but I can't seem to find how to get those specific data out of the box. I did try

```
everything = page2.find("div", class_= "box").text
```

but when I create the new excel folder, the box content all goes in the same cell, which I guess is normal, but its not what I need. I only want the "année" and "kilométrage" data, in seperate columns in the new folder

Comment: If you right click the element you're interested in using Chrome and then click inspect you can find it in the HTML source and then right click there and copy > selector, then you can use this is bs4.

Comment: #description > div:nth-child(5) > p:nth-child(4) > span:nth-child(2) > a

this is what I'm getting.

AM I supposed to paste that in sublime text in page2.find(''paste here'') ? I'm getting a syntax error on each '':''

Comment: Ah unfortunately nth child doesn't work with select. You can either iterate over the children and find the one you're after or use a different method to select.

Comment: I have actually no idea what you just said lmao. Taking this class in journalism, we're currently at our 4th class and nobody understands shit

Comment: Can you post the link to the website? I'll have a look shortly

Comment: https://www.lespac.com/montreal/bmw_b286df286dh0g17567i1j3k1R1.jsa

so i'm basically trying to get the title of each post of the 133 pages of bmw ads on this site, the price, the year and the mileage ''kilométrage''. The title and price were easy as they were simple div/class in the HTML code. but after that im completely clueless, our teacher didnt go as far as explaining how to get spans in other divs and stuff

The picture in post is the actual ad for the first BMW listed

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AoZrb

 this is the code im currently at...